# Detect changes made in virtual machine ovf

Tags: php, linux, ovf

How I Can Detect Ovf File Moved Or Copied?
I built a software engine that is inside a virtual machine and I want to prevent it from copying or transferring it. 
How can i do this?
My software is in PHP and ovf is Linux Cent OS 7.

Comment: I want my software not work when ovf changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UUID BIOS with the following code:

```
dmidecode | grep -i uuid | awk '{print $2}' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

After Change OVF, BIOS UUID changing.